# path is deprecated (django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm)

Tags: python, django

I am working on password reset on django project, when the email address is sent i get

```
path is deprecated (django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm)
```

at the command prompt.

Here is my url.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from doreenselly import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.auth.views import password_reset, password_reset_done, password_reset_confirm, password_reset_complete
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', 'selly.views.index', name="index"),
    url(r'^selly/', include('selly.urls')),
    url(r'^delete_item/(?P<item_id>[-\w]+)/$', views.delete_item, name='delete_item'),
    url(r'^admin_delete_item/(?P<item_id>[-\w]+)/$', views.admin_delete_item, name='admin_delete_item'),

    # Password reset urls
    url(r'^reset/form/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name = 'registration/password_reset_email.html')),
    url(r'^resetpassword/passwordsent/$', password_reset_done, name="password_reset_done"),
    url(r'^reset/password/$', password_reset, name="password_reset"),
    url(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$', password_reset_confirm, name="password_reset_confirm"),
    url(r'^reset/done/$', password_reset_complete, name="password_reset_complete"),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your urls look OK, so my guess is the problem is in your template.

Look for

```
{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}
```

in your `registration/password_reset_email.html` template, and replace it with

```
{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}
```

If that doesn't solve the problem, then you need to find out where the warning is coming from. You can run the dev server with the `-W` flag to [turn warnings into exceptions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#the-warnings-filter).

```
python -W error manage.py runserver
```

When you send the password reset email, you will get a traceback which will show you where the problem is.